# Having a console command work in every user input

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to make a menu command working in every user input, basically, the user is able to move around the program with input

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
switch(input):
{
    case "Up":
        y++;
        Console.WriteLine("Moving up at x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
        break;
    case "Down":
        y--;
        Console.WriteLine("Moving down at x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
        break;
    case "Left":
        x--;
        Console.WriteLine("Moving left at x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
        break;
    case "Right":
        x++;
        Console.WriteLine("Moving right at x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Standing still at x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
        break;
}
```

This will be more or less when the user chooses were to move. What I want to make is a menu command which opens a menu every time it's written, without having to put a "menu" case each time (I'm not putting this switch inside a do while, because I need to customize every move). Is there any way to run a code every time a particular input is given by the user at any time during the whole execution of the program?

Comment: You can use events and delegates.

Comment: @John I don't know how to do it

Comment: @rabink I thought about that but I a little bit confused on how I could use it

Comment: You could use event and delegates but still you will need to wrap the code inside a loop. But you will have flexibility of clearing and subscribing the event to different function at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I've read your question a second time, and it seems like you just need to extract this code into its own method. A simple approach would be to just call `HandleDirectionalInput` from any menu method.

```
public bool HandleDirectionalInput(string input)
{
    switch(input):
    {
        case "Up":
            y++;
            Console.WriteLine("Moving up at x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
            return true;
        case "Down":
            y--;
            Console.WriteLine("Moving down at x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
            return true;
        case "Left":
            x--;
            Console.WriteLine("Moving left at x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
            return true;
        case "Right":
            x++;
            Console.WriteLine("Moving right at x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So you would end up with something like this:

```
public void DoMainMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("some stuff here");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!HandleDirectionalInput(input))
    {
        // do other main menu checks on input
    }
}
```

There are other ways you could do this, such as by creating a list of command handlers which would each have their turn at handling the input, but that's probably more complicated than you need at the moment.